# Unable to connect to the PostgreSQL getting relation "table_name" does not exist error

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

Following is my Java JDBC code, in which I am trying to connect to the PostgreSQL Database "railway"

```
import java.sql.*;

class Jdbc_2{
    public statis void main( String [] args){
       
      Connection C = null;
      Statement stmt = null;

     try{
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/railway", "test". "test123");
        c.setAutoCommit(false);
        System.out.println("Database opened!")
        stmt = c.createStatement();
        String ip1 = "SELECT * FROM railway WHERE stcode1 = " + args[0] + "and stcode2 = " + args[1];
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(ip1);
        if(!rs.next()){
          System.out.println("stcode1 and stcode2 doesn't exits");
        }
        if(rs.next()){
           System.out.println("stcode1 and stcode2 found!")
        }
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
     }
   }
}
```

I can see the "railway" DB created in my postgres.

but still the above code is giving me error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException:ERROR: relation "railway" does not exist

  Position: 16
```

also what is this Position means?

Comment: It means you have a table name (`railway`) at character 16 in your query. And the id you're using to log in to the database does not have access to that table. As such, you get the error you listed.

Comment: railway is a db name in postgres, but in the java code it's a table name.

Comment: You should copy/paste the code here, not put it on an image and drop it somewhere where it can be deleted without any warnin.

Answer (score 1):

The `SELECT * FROM x` is a table query. When you connect to the database you connect to a database within the database software, and that database has tables which the query will be applied to.

Without knowing what your tables are called I can't suggest what it should look like instead, except for that x should be exchanged for the [schema].[tablename]

You find the tables in the db by doing:

```
\c railway  -- Connect to the database
\dt         -- List database tables
```

in the database console.